# Enable/Disable a dropdownbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am new to jQuery and I want to enable and disable a dropdown list using a checkbox. This is my html:

```
<select id="dropdown" style="width:200px">
    <option value="feedback" name="aft_qst">After Quest</option>
    <option value="feedback" name="aft_exm">After Exam</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkdwn2" value="feedback" />
```

What jQuery code do I need to do this? Also searching for a good jQuery documentation/study material.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Here is one way that I hope is easy to understand:

http://jsfiddle.net/tft4t/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#chkdwn2").click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
   } else {
      $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);  
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Note: jQuery 1.6.x utilizes .prop whereas earlier versions utilize .attr

Comment: `$("#chkdwn2").change(function() { $("#dropdown").prop('disabled', !this.checked); })` http://jsfiddle.net/tft4t/74/

Answer (score 15):

I am using JQuery > 1.8 and this works for me...

```
$('#dropDownId').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer(In early 2019) considering each loop etc have performance implications and using the attr method is the most performant way of doing it.

Answer (score 11):

Try -

```
$('#chkdwn2').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $('#dropdown').removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $('#dropdown').attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#chkdwn2").change(function(){
       $("#dropdown").slideToggle();
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZcvG/1/)

Comment: Ill give you a thumbs up just because this is pretty cool...and I didnt know about this function.

Answer (score 2):

To enable/disable -

```
$("#chkdwn2").change(function() { 
    if (this.checked) $("#dropdown").prop("disabled",true);
    else $("#dropdown").prop("disabled",false);
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tTX6E/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#chkdwn2").click(function () {
                if (this.checked)
                    $('#dropdown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                else
                    $('#dropdown').removeAttr('disabled');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**A better solution without if-else:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chkdwn2").click(function() {
        $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", this.checked);  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chkdwn2").change(function() { 
    if (this.checked) $("#dropdown").prop("disabled",'disabled');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#chkdwn2').click(function() {
   if ($('#chkdwn2').prop('checked')) {
      $('#dropdown').prop('disabled', true);
   } else {
      $('#dropdown').prop('disabled', false);  
   }
 });
});
```

making use of `.prop` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

this is to disable dropdown2 , dropdown 3 if you select the option from dropdown1 that has the value 15

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function(){
            if ( $(this).val()!= "15" ) {
                $("#dropdown2").attr("disabled",true);
                $("#dropdown13").attr("disabled",true);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Selector should be either name of select, id (#) or class (.),

**This is if you want to disable:**

```
$("#your-selector").prop("disabled", true);
```

**This is if you want to enable:**

```
$("#your-selector").prop("disabled", false);
```