# Rails: Create a dynamic form where if a checkbox is checked, the other text field is grayed out

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form that asks a customer for subscription term.

It has two options:
1. a drop down where the user selects from number 2 to 99.  (2 weeks to 99 weeks)
2. Or, the user can select a checkbox "Subscribe until I cancel manually".

If the user selects the checkbox "Subscribe until I cancel manually", I would like to gray out / disable the drop down.

What's the eloquent Rails way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails. Show us the HTML, so that we can explain how you can use jQuery to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about jquery/javascript related, not about Rails. Please check this question [Enable/Disable a dropdownbox in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703241/enable-disable-a-dropdownbox-in-jquery)