# How to enable/disable drop down list box in HTML + Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 drop down lists of pairs of name IMEI's and cities, as following:

```
<HTML>

 <body>
Select Programming font:
<select name="IMEI">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">$</option>
</select>

<select name ="city">
  <option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
  <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="Kanpur">Kanpur</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

The desired behavior is: when one selects a city name, the IMEI list enables; otherwise it is disabled.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703241/enable-disable-a-dropdownbox-in-jquery

Comment: Just to point out the obvious - your city dropdown will already have "Jhansi" selected.  As a user I would be mighty annoyed to have to select a different city in order to enable the IMEI dropdown, if I wanted to select Jhansi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cdL83/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    var sel_imie = $('select[name="IMEI"]');
    sel_imei.prop('disabled', true); //disable IMEI select
    $('select[name ="city"]').change(function () {
        sel_imei.prop('disabled', false); //enable when value of city select is changed
    });
});
```

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<select name="IMEI" disabled="disabled" id="IMEI">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">$</option>
</select>

<select name ="city" id="city">
  <option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
  <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="Kanpur">Kanpur</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$('#city').on('change',function(){

$('#IMEI').attr('disabled',false);
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/khmSm/

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Programming font:
<select name="IMEI" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">$</option>
</select>
<select name="city">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="Kanpur">Kanpur</option>
</select>

document.getElementsByName('city')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var imei = document.getElementsByName('IMEI')[0];
    var city = e.target;
    imei.disabled = city.value != '' ? '' : 'disabled';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
   CITY :<select name="city">
           <option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
           <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
           <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
           <option value="Kanpur">Kanpur</option>
         </select>
         <br/>

   IMEI :<select name="IMEI">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">$</option>
         </select>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
   $('select[name=IMEI]').prop('disabled',true);
   $('select[name=city]').on('change',function () {
        $('select[name=IMEI]').prop('disabled',false);
   });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/TvpRF/7/

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="IMEI" disabled="disabled" id="IMEI">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">$</option>
</select>

<select name ="city" id="city">
 <option value ="choose">Choose a city</option>
 <option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
 <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
 <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
 <option value="Kanpur">Kanpur</option>
</select>
```

Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/khmSm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Disable select and update the plugin. Use trigger chosen:updated to disable the select widget.

```
$('#RefundType').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
```