# Multi checkbox requirement enable disable dropdown box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So first off I did search and I found this [Enable/Disable a dropdownbox in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703241/enable-disable-a-dropdownbox-in-jquery) which got me on the right track.  I'm new to jquery so when seeing other code I can adapt it to fit and work for me.

So what i'm asking is how do you make it check to see if two check boxes condition are true?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#box1").click(function() {
           if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
              $("#tech1").prop("disabled", false);
           } else {
              $("#tech1").prop("disabled", true);  
           }
         });
        });
</script>
```

I want it to be if box1 and box2 are checked enable this box?  I understand you can do it with an if statement, but I'm not sure where exactly it goes.  Thanks in advance.

Would this work:

```
$("#box1").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) &&
$("#box2").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
```

I doesn't work and I assume thats because that above creates two functions and not the if statement that I need.

Comment: Could you provide the markup including the checkbox? It sounds like you need a simple && operator in your conditional statement, but to give a better answer, the markup would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include both in the event handler, and check if both are checked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var boxes = $("#box1, #box2");

    boxes.on('change',  function() {

       var disabled = boxes.filter(':checked').length === boxes.length;

       $("#tech1").prop("disabled", disabled);

    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0cfmv19t/)

Comment: Since this works how would i add a 3 element in the mix which is a drop down box (2 checkboxes and 1 dropdown) to check if it is selected?  Once that is selected I then enable the final box.  Now the form can be submitted.

Comment: can you flip this from being enable to disable to disable to enable?

Comment: here is the last thing i'm trying to accomplish... check the first box and 2nd to enable the 3rd to choose from a dropdown, finally enabling the last box to be selected -> http://jsfiddle.net/0cfmv19t/5/

Comment: while working through all the different possibilities, I did run into a problem.  Its when i go to a page that box 1, box2, and dropdown are are already have an active value, the last box should be enabled allowing the user to check it.  Right now it disabled until i select a different value for the dropdown and it becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **box1 & box2** checkboxes defined with a css class **boxes** as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" class="boxes" />
<input type="checkbox" id="box2" class="boxes" />
```

Now you can use box class as jquery selector to do your task

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".boxes").click(function(){
         if($(".boxes:checked").size() == $(".boxes").size()){
            $("#tech1").prop("disabled", false);
         }else{
            $("#tech1").prop("disabled", true);  
         }
     );
});
```