# Disable dropdownlist in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to disable a dropdownlist with jQuery code below. In IE 11 the dropdownlist  is disabled but in chrome it remains enabled. Any one know of a much more reliable way of getting this to work across browsers?

```
 if (!userEmail.trim()) {
            $("#DropDownList1").dropdownchecklist("disable");
         }
```

And below is the definition of the dropdownlist

```
<div id="divList">
  @Html.DropDownList("DropDownList1", new SelectList(ViewBag.MyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text", 0))
</div>
```

Comment: Your question does not mention `dropdownchecklist`, only your code. Is dropdownchecklist a jQuery plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable/Disable a dropdownbox in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703241/enable-disable-a-dropdownbox-in-jquery)

Comment: Did any of these answers help you at all?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#DropDownList1").prop("disabled", true);
```

Here's a fiddle too:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5es6na0/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
$("#dropDown").attr("disabled", true);
```

This will work for all browsers